# Custom 404 on Azure Websites

Tags: iis, azure, visual-studio-2013, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I've hosted a Azure Website via GitHub and want to make a custom 404 page.
My VisualStudio2013 is connected to Azure. How can access to the web.config?
If i want to take the way via FTP - how can i access it with my VS2013?
Is it possible to set up the custom 404 via the Azure portal?

Currently i get the standardpage:

```
Error 404 - Web Site not found!

The website you have attempted to reach is
not available in this Microsoft Azure Web Sites
region. This could be due to one of several
reasons:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit the web.config file in your Visual Studio solution, modify the customErrors section and then check the file into Github to trigger a new deployment. The Azure documentation site has a [full example of this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/).

Comment: It isn't a Visual Studio Solution.
So there isn't any web.config file in my VS.

Comment: Find your web.config file then :).  Worst case scenario you can edit it directly from the D:\home\site\wwwroot folder of your site on Azure