# .htaccess seems doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess

What I was trying to do is making a customised page for 404 page. But seems does not work.
This is the code of .htaccess file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 404notfound.php
```

The 404notfound.php is my customised page. I'm using Microsoft Azure for web server. I'm wondering why it does't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change it to `ErrorDocument 404 /404notfound.php`

Comment: @Raj_King Thank you for response. Still doesn't work, I tried `ErrorDocument 404 http://google.com` but still doesn't work.

Comment: Does Azure support .htaccess?

Comment: Your .htaccess and your 404notfound.php file are in same path?

Comment: You may want to check this answer to see how Azure supports custom 404 pages: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29030267/1824988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using Microsoft Azure for web server.

That is why it doesn't work. `.htaccess` files are an Apache HTTPD feature.

Microsoft Azure runs on Microsoft IIS which you configure [with `system.web` files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bfb8349a-4676-45a1-88dc-de988fff9bb8/custom-error-pages-not-working-in-azure?forum=windowsazuredevelopment).

Comment: Thanks Quentin, I use Netbeans for IDE, and there is no system.web files I can see in Source Files folder. Where can I set the configuration?